# HTTP Basic with Spring Security XML configuration doesn't use HttpBasicConfigurer

Tags: java, spring-security

It seems that XML configuration and Java are not performing the same tasks in Spring Security, regarding the HTTP Basic configuration.

When using the following Java configuration:

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
  http
    .httpBasic()
  .and()
    .authorizeRequests()
      .anyRequest().authenticated();
}
```

A `HttpBasicConfigurer` is used in order to use a different EntryPoint, when the request HTTP header `X-Requested-With` is `XMLHttpRequest`.

When using the configuration

```
<s:http use-expressions="true" create-session="ifRequired">
     <s:intercept-url pattern='/**' access='isAuthenticated()' />
     <s:http-basic />
<s:http />
```

The `HTTPBassicConfigurer` is not used.

Anybody knows how to add it using the XML configuration ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The final solution based on the remarks provided by the people in this post, is that it is not possible to use `HTTPBasicConfigurer` with XML configuration. But there are other ways to perform almost the same thing that is implemented now in `HTTPBasicConfigurer`. My final solution used is mainly based on the remarks provided by Lea:

```
<s:http use-expressions="true" create-session="ifRequired" >
    <s:intercept-url pattern='/**' access='isAuthenticated()' />
    <s:http-basic entry-point-ref="entryPoint" /> 
</s:http>

<bean id="entryPoint"
      class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication
                                .DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <constructor-arg>
        <map>
            <entry key="hasHeader('X-Requested-With','XMLHttpRequest')" 
                   value-ref="ajaxEntyPoint" />
        </map>
    </constructor-arg>
    <property name="defaultEntryPoint" ref="defaultEntryPoint"/>        
</bean>

<bean id="ajaxEntyPoint" 
      class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.HttpStatusEntryPoint">
    <constructor-arg name="httpStatus" 
                     value="#{T(org.springframework.http.HttpStatus).UNAUTHORIZED}"/>
</bean>

<bean id="defaultEntryPoint"
      class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www
                                             .BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <property name="realmName" value="My webservices"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering your own question, not everyone does this when they found a solution! One small remark to clean up the answer: change **ajaxEntyPoint** to **ajaxEntryPoint**

Answer (score 1):

Basic authentication parameters can be declared explicitly with basic authentication filter:

```
<security:http use-expressions="true" entry-point-ref="entryPoint" authentication-manager-ref="authManager">
        <security:custom-filter ref="advancedBasicFilter" position="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/info/**" access="permitAll" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
</security:http>

<bean id="advancedBasicFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter">
    <constructor-arg name="authenticationEntryPoint" ref="entryPoint"/>
    <constructor-arg name="authenticationManager" ref="authManager"/>
</bean>

<bean id="entryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <property name="realmName" value="My Realm"/>
</bean>

<security:authentication-manager id="authManager">
    <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="myOwnUserService" />
</security:authentication-manager>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Lea. Actually, I don't see how this code might solve my problem. I still can't see how to use HTTPBasicConfigurer with the code you are suggesting. My primary requirement  is to have a different EntryPoint depending on the request header `X-Requested-With` which is exactely what is done by the HTTPBasicConfigurer. Or at least, do you see any other way to perform that using XML configuration ?

Comment: I understood you now. Take a look at [DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.1.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint.html)

Comment: Thanks Lea ! Finally, I managed to fix implement some code almost equal to what is implemented within `HTTPBasicConfigurer` based on your remarks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using xml config with the namespace, you do not use a `HTTPBasicConfigurer`, but attributes of the `<http-basic>` tag.

Extract from Spring Security Reference Manual Appendix The security namespace about `<http-basic>` tag :

*Attributes*

- *authentication-details-source-ref : Reference to an `AuthenticationDetailsSource` which will be used by the authentication filter*
- *entry-point-ref Sets the `AuthenticationEntryPoint` which is used by the BasicAuthenticationFilter*